# How to dynamically add IO ports to a Chisel Bundle?

Tags: chisel

How can you dynamically add inputs or outputs to a Bundle in order to achieve the equivalent of this pseudocode.

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle {
  for( i <- 1 to 10) {
     val foo_<i> = UInt(i.W)
  }
}
```

Note that I would like to not only create 10 dynamic ports but would also like that the index value would be reflected in the port name and port size. I think MixedVec cast to Bundle can potentially offer something similar not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is use `Record` instead of Bundle. Here's a pointer to the chisel3 test of the `Record` construct [RecordSpec.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/RecordSpec.scala)

As an example based on your pseudocode. It would look like this

```
  class MyBundle extends Record {
    val elements = ListMap(Seq.tabulate(10) { i =>
      s"foo_$i" -> UInt(i.W)
    }:_*)
    override def cloneType: this.type = (new MyBundle).asInstanceOf[this.type]
  }
```